# Writing to a shared partition

Tags: permissions, mount, groups

I am aware that there are many questions about write permissions and partitions, but I have followed the instructions that I found to the letter and double checked everything I can think of, and I cannot figure out why this doesn't work...

I have an internal HDD formatted as Ext4 mounted at `/scratch` by default at startup, the corresponding line in `/etc/fstab` is:

```
# /scratch was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=3e79213f-e065-4a43-be61-253c66264dfb /scratch        ext4    defaults
```

I know that using `defaults` implies `nouser` but that is fine; I don't want users to be able to mount/unmount this partition.

I want this to be a scratch space shared by all local users, so I created a new group, set the permissions to the mounted folder, and added myself to that group:

```
sudo groupadd ScratchUser
sudo chgrp -R ScratchUser /scratch
sudo chmod -R 2775 /scratch
sudo usermod -a -G ScratchUser myself
```

So that folder is still owned by root, but has `rwx` persmissions for a group that I am a member of. That makes sense to me, but now when I try to create a file within that folder:

```
myself@machine:~$ touch /scratch/foo
touch: cannot touch '/scratch/foo': Permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have done everything right. I think you should just need to logoff and log back on again.

I have replicated your scenario here, and everything worked fine after I logged of and on again.